# How to get a list of IDS from first and second level array

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have the following structure in JSON/JavaScript:

```json
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "content": "lorem ipsum",
      "answers": []
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "content": "lorem ipsum",
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": 30,
          "content": "lorem ipsum"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "content": "lorem ipsum",
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": 99,
          "content": "lorem ipsum"
        },
        {
          "id": 103,
          "content": "lorem ipsum"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "content": "comment",
      "answers": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to create an array containing the id of all comments, including answers type comments

The end should look like this

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 30, 99, 103]
```

Can I just use `map`, `reduce` and `filter`?

What can I try next?

Comment: For all `id` fields in object: `let ids = JSON.stringify(obj.comments).match(/\"?id\"?\:(\d+)\,/g).map((id)=>{return parseInt(id.replace(/\"?id\"?\:(\d+)\,/,'$1'));});`. Not accurate solution but gives output as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can also use `flat`:

```js
const data = {comments:[{id:1,content:"lorem ipsum",answers:[]},{id:2,content:"lorem ipsum",answers:[{id:30,content:"lorem ipsum"}]},{id:3,content:"lorem ipsum",answers:[{id:99,content:"lorem ipsum"},{id:103,content:"lorem ipsum"}]},{id:5,content:"comment",answers:[]}]};

function findIds(obj) {
  return obj.comments.map(com => {
    return [ com.id, ...com.answers.map(ans => ans.id) ]
  })
  .flat()
  .sort((a, b) => a - b);
}

console.log( findIds(data) ); // [1,2,3,5,30,99,103]
```

Otherwise, just using `map` and `reduce`:

```js
const data = {comments:[{id:1,content:"lorem ipsum",answers:[]},{id:2,content:"lorem ipsum",answers:[{id:30,content:"lorem ipsum"}]},{id:3,content:"lorem ipsum",answers:[{id:99,content:"lorem ipsum"},{id:103,content:"lorem ipsum"}]},{id:5,content:"comment",answers:[]}]};

function findIds(obj) {
  return obj.comments.reduce((res, com) => {
    return [ ...res, com.id, ...com.answers.map(ans => ans.id) ]
  }, [])
  .sort((a, b) => a - b);
}

console.log( findIds(data) ); // [1,2,3,5,30,99,103]
```

Comment: Ok, I added sorting

Comment: what is `...res`?

Comment: @YungSilva Sorry, since you mentioned `reduce`, I thought you knew how to use it. It's the `result` being built. It's called the "accumulator" in [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Or maybe you were talking about the `...`? This is the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It's basically equivalent to doing `res.concat(otherArray)` (mergin arrays together)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your required output using [`Spread_syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)/ [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method of array.

Please have a look into below code snippet:

**ES6**

```js
var obj = {"comments":[{"id":1,"content":"lorem ipsum","answers":[]},{"id":2,"content":"lorem ipsum","answers":[{"id":30,"content":"lorem ipsum"}]},{"id":3,"content":"lorem ipsum","answers":[{"id":99,"content":"lorem ipsum"},{"id":103,"content":"lorem ipsum"}]},{"id":5,"content":"comment","answers":[]}]};

let result = obj.comments.reduce((r,o)=>[...r, o.id,...o.answers.map(v=>v.id)],[]);

console.log(result.sort((a,b)=> a-b));
```

**ES5**

```js
var data = {"comments":[{"id":1,"content":"lorem ipsum","answers":[]},{"id":2,"content":"lorem ipsum","answers":[{"id":30,"content":"lorem ipsum"}]},{"id":3,"content":"lorem ipsum","answers":[{"id":99,"content":"lorem ipsum"},{"id":103,"content":"lorem ipsum"}]},{"id":5,"content":"comment","answers":[]}]};

//This function will return the all id's from the passed array as per above object data.
function getIDs(obj) {
  var result = obj.comments.reduce(function(res, item) {
    var answers = item.answers.map(function(ans) {
      return ans.id;
    });
    res.push(item.id);//Adding id in array from main list
    return res.concat(answers);//Using contact method for add both arrays values 
  }, []);

  return result.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
}


console.log(getIDs(data));
```

Comment: what is `...r`?

Comment: @YungSilva `...r` is [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

your JSON: data__ = { ... }

```
let result = []
let innerObjs = []
for (let i = 0; i < data__.comments.length; i++){
    let obj = data__.comments[i].id
    result.push(obj)
    innerObjs.push(data__.comments[i].answers)
}
for(let a = 0; a < innerObjs.length; a ++){
    let answers = innerObjs[a]
    for(let j =0; j < answers.length; j++){
        let ans = answers[j]
        if(ans)             
            result.push(ans.id)
    }
}
console.log(result)
```